# How to use ng-selected when using ng-options

Tags: angularjs

How to use the ng-selected when using ng-options for the drop down list.

Kindly refer the below plukr.

```
$scope.dist_list_e = [
{major_id: '1', minor_id: '1', gi_code: '21810030000'},
{major_id: '1', minor_id: '2', gi_code: '21810040000'},
{major_id: '2', minor_id: '3', gi_code: '21810050000'},
{major_id: '5', minor_id: '5', gi_code: '21810060000'}

];
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/XKJACU3N7iHclAYJZoDT

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select name="major_head" class="browser-default" ng-change="major_change($index)" data-ng-model="dist_list_e[$index].major_head" data-ng-options="I.id as I.name for I in major_head_list track by I.id">
        <option value="">Choose your option</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to be preselected?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this API from angular  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

> Note: ngSelected does not interact with the select and ngModel
>   directives, it only sets the selected attribute on the element. If you
>   are using ngModel on the select, you should not use ngSelected on the
>   options, as ngModel will set the select value and selected options.

Comment: I tried but its not working. Could you please try in plunker?

Answer (score 0):

ng-selected should go in option tag not select tag. You should be using ng-model for your selected model not the array, please take a look at my updates below with your script:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.major_head_list = [
        {id: '1', name: 'CAPEX'},
        {id: '2', name: 'Supplier Advance'},
        {id: '3', name: 'Salary Payable'},
        {id: '4', name: 'Employee Benefits'},
        {id: '5', name: 'TDS'}
    ];
    $scope.minor_head_list = [
        {id: '1', name: 'Office Equipment'},
        {id: '2', name: 'Furniture & Fixtures'},
        {id: '3', name: 'OPEX'},
        {id: '4', name: 'Insurance'},
        {id: '5', name: 'TDS on Vendors'}
    ];

    $scope.dist_list_e = [
        {major_id: '1', minor_id: '1', gi_code: '21810030000'},
        {major_id: '1', minor_id: '2', gi_code: '21810040000'},
        {major_id: '2', minor_id: '3', gi_code: '21810050000'},
        {major_id: '5', minor_id: '5', gi_code: '21810060000'}
    ];

    $scope.selected_major_head_list = $scope.major_head_list[0];
});
```

And to your select tag:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select name="major_head" class="browser-default" ng-change="major_change($index)"
        data-ng-model="selected_major_head_list" data-ng-options="I.id as I.name for I in major_head_list track by I.id" >
        <option value="">Choose your option</option>
    </select>
</div>
```